# OpenSSL install issue to MAC

Tags: macos, openssl, osx-lion

I tried to install openSSL to my MAC but I did not. I watched the steps below, but I could not understand exactly what you should do. I am a new mac user. Please tell us about what to do as a simple

Step 1) Download OpenSSL 0.9.6c here: http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-0.9.6c.tar.gz

Step 2) Uncompress the archive and rename the resulting folder "openssl"

step 3) Open up the terminal and type cd /users/YOURUSERNAME/desktop/

step 4) type sudo mv openssh /usr/local/

step 5) type sudo cd /usr/local/openssl

step 6) type ./config

step 7) type make

step 8) type make install

Comment: OpenSSL is already installed. Why do you need to build it from source? You also seem to be confusing openssh and openssl.  But you don't need openssh either because you already get a ssh command installed as well.

Comment: I did not step 7. İf I tried then I see this message "-bash: make: command not found "

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. SSL is already installed so why do you need to build it from source?

Comment: Because I want for IOS push notification

Comment: aoneki in case you didn't solve the issue, I think why you thought you didn't have SSL in your machine: is it possible that, being new to the mac world you don't really understand the concept of terminal and commands, so you copy+past an instruction from the web such as `$ openssl x509 -in ...`. Well the answer really is easy: DON'T copy the $ together with the instruction :)

Answer (score 6):

> Download OpenSSL 0.9.6c here

Man, 0.9.6 is old. Are you sure you want/need it?

---

Here's the recipe using OpenSSL 1.0.1f:

```
$ wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz

$ tar xzf openssl-1.0.1f.tar.gz

$ cd openssl-1.0.1f

$ ./Configure darwin64-x86_64-cc

$ make all

$ sudo make install
```

If you are on an old 32-bit Mac, then use `./Configure darwin-i386-cc`.

There's no need to build in `/usr/local` using `sudo`. In fact, its preferred to compile under an unprivileged account and only elevate during install.

---

OpenSSL comes with 0.9.8. To ensure you use the copy of OpenSSL you just downloaded, built and installed:

```
gcc -I/usr/local/ssl/include <your source files> -o <your prog name> -L/usr/local/ssl/lib -lssl -lcrypto -lpthread -ldl
```

The trick is that OpenSSL installs into `/usr/local/ssl`. So you find headers in `/usr/local/ssl/include` and libraries in `/usr/local/ssl/lib`.